# Jenkins Job DSL sshAgent not working correctly

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

For the Jenkins Job DSL, I am trying to choose specific ssh agent (plugin) keys for a job (using the sshAgent keyword inside the wrappers context).  We have the Jenkins ssh agent plugin installed and several keys setup (this plugin works, as we use it for almost all of our jobs).  The Jenkins Job DSL sshAgent command  always picks the first key, regardless of whether I specify a different key in our Jenkins setup.

I have tried using just the key name, but also tried key_name + space + description (just like the dropdowns show).  That does not work either -- still picks the first key.

Is this a known issue?  (I haven't turned up any searches for this yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the ID of the credentials to the `sshAgent` DSL method. To get the ID, install at least version 1.21 of the [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin). Then navigate to the credentials you want to use, e.g. if the credentials you want to use are global and called "Your Credentials" go to Jenkins > Credentials > Global credentials (unrestricted) > Your Credentials > Update. Then click the "Advanced..." button to reveal the ID. If you did not specify a custom ID when creating the credentials, it's a UUID like `99add9e9-84d4-408a-b644-9162a93ee3e4`. Then use this value in your DSL script.

```
job('example') {
  wrappers {
    sshAgent('99add9e9-84d4-408a-b644-9162a93ee3e4')
  }
}
```

It's recommended to use a recognizable custom ID when creating new credentials, e.g. `deployment-key`. That will lead to readable DSL scripts.

```
job('example') {
  wrappers {
    sshAgent('deployment-key')
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks so much!